# SWFUpload generates error 500 on production server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, swfupload

I am using SWFUpload on my website. When I test the SWFUploader on my dev machine it works perfectly fine. However, when I move to production then it says `error 500' I checked the file type and file size but there seems no issue or conflict. I am using almost the standard settings..

```
     upload1 = new SWFUpload({
        // Backend Settings
        upload_url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/UserProfile/Photos.aspx") %>',


        // File Upload Settings
        file_size_limit: "1024*5", // 5MB
        file_types: "*.bmp; *.gif; *.jpeg; *.jpg; *.png;",
        file_types_description: "Image Files",
        file_upload_limit: "10",
        file_queue_limit: "0",

        // Event Handler Settings (all my handlers are in the Handler.js file)
        file_dialog_start_handler: fileDialogStart,
        file_queued_handler: fileQueued,
        file_queue_error_handler: fileQueueError,
        file_dialog_complete_handler: fileDialogComplete,
        upload_start_handler: uploadStart,
        upload_progress_handler: uploadProgress,
        upload_error_handler: uploadError,
        upload_success_handler: uploadSuccess,
        upload_complete_handler: uploadComplete,
        // Button Settings
        button_image_url: "../Images/XPButtonUploadText_61x22.png",
        button_placeholder_id: "spanButtonPlaceholder1",
        button_width: 61,
        button_height: 22,
        // Flash Settings
        flash_url: "../SWFUploader/swfupload.swf",


        custom_settings: {
            progressTarget: "fsUploadProgress1",
            cancelButtonId: "btnCancel1"
        },

        // Debug Settings
        debug: false
    });
```

what can possibly be the reason for this error..

Comment: Does the path `~/UserProfile/Photos.aspx` exist in production server?

Comment: :o  Yes... it does exists

Comment: Is there any error stack trace in your application log? Seems like `Photos.aspx` is crashing

Comment: I get error `internal server error 500` in console of browser nothing else

Comment: There should be some information in the server log. If you cannot access it, there's little we can do...

Comment: where is that log ???

Comment: I have not configured the web_event_log yet

Comment: `Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 7/3/2013 1:25:17 AM
Event time (UTC): 7/3/2013 8:25:17 AM
Event ID: 4594abc667f2414cadfc55b60fed1ccd
Event sequence: 54
Event occurrence: 1
Event detail code: 0

Application information:    Machine name: WIN10

Process information:
    Process ID: 22276
    Process name: w3wp.exe
    

Exception information:
    Exception type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
    Exception message: A generic error occurred in GDI+.`

Comment: I have removed other details as the message was too long... the error seems to be with GDI+